# ntp client does not work with DD-wrt using PPPOE as wan

Tags: dd-wrt, ntp

ntp client does not work with DD-wrt using PPPOE as wan

tried different firmwares, facotory resets, different routers cant get it to wrk..
works fine with 2009 firmware on wrt54g (works with default settings)

on asus n16/n66u no luck

thank you

Comment: What OS, NTP is a function of the OS not hardware

Comment: dd-wrt.. yes its a function of OS but different versions of hard ware with different version of dd-wrt may work

Comment: You should clarify that the NTP client within dd-wRt isn't functional not the NTP client on the network client (which I assume you were talking about)